# pydev explorer ignores symbolic links

Tags: eclipse, pydev, aptana3

I am using Apatana Studio inside Eclipse on a Linux host maintaining a django site using python. Some of the python modules included in the site are simply symbolic links to the installed packages. We don't want copies of modules maintained elsewhere, we just want to use them so we use links into the sites PYTHONPATH dir.

Pydev explorer (the file browsing tool in Aptana Studio) ignores these links so the files of the included modules cannot be viewed in Eclipse. This problem was reported in 2007 (http://sourceforge.net/p/pydev/bugs/523/). I am hoping by posting here that someone will respond with status or a work around.

Thanks,

< david